# MFC: Dialog box not displaying after keystroke

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, modal-dialog

thank you for you time in advance.

Very new to MFC and attempting to finish a cs project before Sunday. We are to create a simple program that displays polygons in a grid. Rectangles are working great, but as I begin to add triangles, I cannot for the of me figure out why the triangle dialog box refuses to display. Here is some code:

CEquilDialog.h:

```
 #include <afxwin.h>

class CEquilDialog : public CDialog {
public:
    CEquilDialog();
    afx_msg void OnOK();
    afx_msg void OnCancel();
    int m_nSideLength;
    COLORREF m_Color;
private:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

CEquilDialog.cpp:

```
#include "CEquilDialog.h"
#include "CEquilateralIds.h"

const int TEXT_MAX = 20;

CEquilDialog::CEquilDialog() : CDialog("Equilateral Traingle") {
    m_nSideLength = 0;
}

afx_msg void CEquilDialog::OnOK() {
    char editText[TEXT_MAX + 1];
    CEdit* SideLengthEdit = (CEdit* )(GetDlgItem(IDC_SideLength));
    SideLengthEdit->GetWindowText(editText,TEXT_MAX);
    m_nSideLength = atoi(editText);
    if (m_nSideLength <= 0) {
        EndDialog(!IDOK);
        return;
    }
    int color = GetCheckedRadioButton(IDC_Red, IDC_Blue);
    switch(color) {
        case IDC_Red:
            m_Color = RGB(255,0,0);
            break;
        case IDC_Yellow:
            m_Color = RGB(255,255,0);
            break;
        case IDC_Blue:
            m_Color = RGB(0,0,255);
            break;
        default:
            m_Color = RGB(255,255,255);
    }
    EndDialog(IDOK);
}
afx_msg void CEquilDialog::OnCancel() {
    m_nSideLength = 0;
    EndDialog(!IDOK);
}   

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEquilDialog, CDialog)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_OK, OnOK)
    ON_COMMAND(IDC_Cancel, OnCancel)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

CEquilateralIds.h

```
#define IDC_OK          2000
#define IDC_Cancel      2011
#define IDC_SideLength  2012
#define IDC_Red         2013
#define IDC_Yellow      2014
#define IDC_Blue        2015
```

Equilateral.rc (resource file)

```
#include <afxres.h>
#include "CEquilateralIds.h"

Equilateral DIALOG 50,50,150,150
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU

CAPTION "Create Triangle"
{
    LTEXT "Enter Side Length", IDC_STATIC, 10, 5, 50, 8
    EDITTEXT IDC_SideLength, 25, 15, 60, 16
    GROUPBOX "Select color", IDC_STATIC, 10, 70, 60+15, 50
    AUTORADIOBUTTON "Red", IDC_Red, 25, 80, 50, 16, WS_GROUP
    AUTORADIOBUTTON "Yellow", IDC_Yellow, 25, 91, 50, 16
    AUTORADIOBUTTON "Blue", IDC_Blue, 25, 102, 50, 16
    PUSHBUTTON "OK", IDC_OK, 10, 125, 30, 15, NOT WS_TABSTOP
    PUSHBUTTON "Cancel", IDC_Cancel, 10+60+15, 125, 30, 15, NOT WS_TABSTOP
}
```

All of this code is *identical* to my rectangle files (same files just with rectangle instead of equil, also with height and width instead of just SideLength) -- and here is the CShapesWin.cpp (where the dialog box gets called):

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "CShapesWin.h"
#include "CRectDialog.h"
#include "CEquilDialog.h"
#include "CRectangleIds.h"
#include "CEquilateralIds.h"

CShapesWin::CShapesWin() {
    Create(NULL, "DrawShapes");
}

afx_msg void CShapesWin::OnPaint() {
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    m_doc.Paint(dc, rect);
}

afx_msg void CShapesWin::OnKeyDown(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags) {
    CRectDialog rectDialog;
    CEquilDialog equilDialog;
    switch(nChar) {
        case 38: // Up arrow
        case 40: // Down arrow
            // Pop up a dialog box and get the response
            if (rectDialog.DoModal() == IDOK) {
                if (m_doc.Add(new CRectangle(rectDialog.m_nHeight, 
                    rectDialog.m_nWidth, rectDialog.m_Color)) == TRUE) {
                        Invalidate(TRUE);
                }
            }
            break;
        case 39: // Right arrow
        case 37: // Left arrow
            if (equilDialog.DoModal() == IDOK) {
                if (m_doc.Add(new CEquilateral(equilDialog.m_nSideLength, 
                    equilDialog.m_Color)) == TRUE) {
                        Invalidate(TRUE);
                }
            }
            else {
                MessageBox("Whoops, no dialoge box... :(");
            }
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox("Key not recognized");
    }
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CShapesWin, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_KEYDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

With debugging, I have seen the call to equilDialog.DoModel() attempt to be called, but it fails everytime, whereas my rect.Dialog.DoModel() never fails.... I am at a complete lost, if anyone could help I would be so grateful!

EDIT: Thank you Brian, It seems I forgot how to use a computer! Here is a public link with the zip file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1734050/SO%20Polygon%20Project.zip

EDIT 2: Martin, Thank you so much, The only thing I had to do was make sure that the string in the CEquilDialog.cpp file matched in the resource file. Once I did that, the dialog box worked like a charm.

FOR ANYONE new to MFC and having Dialog box issues, please remeber the following:

In any of your dialog.cpp files when you declare the constructor:

`CYourDialog::CYourDialog() : CDialog("StringToMatchInResourceFile") { 
    m_nSomeVariable = 0;
}`

the "StringToMatchInResourceFile" must *also* be in the .rc file:

```
#include <afxres.h>
#include "CEquilateralIds.h"

StringToMatchInResourceFile DIALOG 50,50,150,150
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
...
```

What I did was have "Equilateral Triangle" in the dialog.cpp and then "Equilateral" in the .rc file. MFC Newbies, **take note!**a

Comment: You can't PM on Stack Overflow. Zip the files, and post a single link to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dialog resource can't be found. When you call the base class constructor :CDialog("Equilateral Triangles"), you're telling MFC and the dialog manager that you have a dialog template resource with the string id "Equilateral Triangles". But your rc file doesn't have that. It has a dialog resource with the id Equilateral (which I don't see you define anywhere). Instead add IDD_EQUILATERAL as 101 to equilateralids.h and refer to it in the CDialog constructor.

It probably works right for the other case because your ID and its string match.

As an added point, without special mechanics you only get one .rc file per project. So if by chance you have two rc files, merge them into one file. This may also be going wrong because the second RC file isn't going anywhere at all.

Martyn

Comment: Martyn, I cannot thank you enough for your advice. I will attempt to make these changes in the morning and will report my hopeful success! Thank you so much for your kindness, and please excuse my poor understanding of MFC.